# nextuntil is not working for grouping input with surrounding text using JQuery

Tags: jquery

Below is the HTML and script code

```js
$('input[type=radio]').each(function(){
$(this).add(this.nextSibling).nextUntil('input').addBack().wrapAll('<label/>');
});
```

```html
<div id="formelements">
<input type="radio"/> yes <br/>
<input type="radio"/> No <br/>
<input type="radio"/>Select <b>or</b> deselect<br/>
<input type="button" value="submit"/>
</div>
```

When I render above code, label tag is properly wrapped for Yes and No elements but it is not properly labelled for "select or deselect". Below is the output generated for above mentioned code
**Existing output:**

```html
<div id="formelements">
<label><input type="radio"> yes <br></label>
<label><input type="radio"> No <br></label>
<label><input type="radio">Select<b>or</b><br></label>deselect
<input type="button" value="submit">
</div>
```

**Required output:**

```html
<div id="formelements">
<label><input type="radio"> yes <br></label>
<label><input type="radio"> No <br></label>
<label><input type="radio">Select<b>or</b>deselect<br></label>
<input type="button" value="submit">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, slightly different because text is not actual HTML elements
Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/veqbch51/

```
$('input[type=radio]').each(function() {
  var $set = $();
  var nxt = this.nextSibling;
  $set.push(this);
  while (nxt) {
    if (!$(nxt).is('input')) {
      $set.push(nxt);
      nxt = nxt.nextSibling;
    } else break;
  }
  $set.wrapAll('<label/>');
});
```